# C++ [std::regex] trying to match only numbers with spaces in between

Tags: c++, regex

I'm working on a card game in C++ where I want to get some user input via getline(). The input needs to be in **this specific format:**

**"1 2 3 4 5 6"**

The range of numbers is **1-11** and each number must be **seperated with a space.** The user is putting in index numbers for a vector. Say he writes "1 2 3" and hits enter, position 0, 1 and 2 are being adressed by the vector.

I'm also open for any other recommendations considering the design decision to let the user input the vector (or essentially their card's) position.

The player cards are displayed in this format "1 blue" and are stored as strings in a vector. I figured it is too much hassle for the user to input the whole card name, so I chose to use the vector index.

Below is the code snippet of my regex string. It works, kinda. It just pushes the whole string in the vector, missing the 10. But I don't need 1 vector element like this: "1 2 3 4", I need 4 vector elements with every number being one element.

**Things that shouldn't match:**

"1234567"

"abcdef"

"12 34 567 32"

If you need any further context, I will gladly provide so.

Thanks in advance

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    std::regex rx("([[:digit:]]\\s)+([[:digit:]]\\s)+");
    std::string line = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10";
    std::smatch m;
    std::vector<std::string> catchit;

    while (regex_search(line, m, rx))
    {
        std::cout << "Pattern found " << m[i] << '\n';
        catchit.push_back(m[i]);
        line = m.suffix().str();
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mention that 12 should not match, but 10 should? Are you really stuck on regex for this? IMO it's easier to solve without it.

Comment: 12 shouldn't match because the maxsize of the vector would be 11. I'm essentially trying to get error handling in for getline(). And since I need such a specific pattern, I figured regex might be the way to do it. I'm definintely open for other suggestions though.

Comment: Why not std::cin? Or wrap your output from getline in a std::stringstream and use operator>> to read numbers one at a time and validate them then? E.g. `std::stringstream stream(line); /* loop */ stream >> val; if (val < 0 || val > 11) ...`

Comment: This is the regex you need `(?:\s|^)([1-9]|1[01])(?!\S)` value is in group 1 every match.

Comment: If possible, use string iterators with the `while ( regex_search() )` it's more efficient I believe.

Comment: Do you want to iterate over the string, or would you like a single expression that will validate the entire line?

Comment: @Nick I am actually using that exact stringstream construction, which works very well for getting the numbers in. I don't know why I didn't think about checking the numbers after reading them in the stream but thank you. That simplifies my problem by a mile. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves my problem without having to use regex, thank you very much @Nick

> Why not std::cin? Or wrap your output from getline in a
>   std::stringstream and use operator>> to read numbers one at a time and
>   validate them then? E.g. std::stringstream stream(line); /* loop */
>   stream >> val; if (val < 0 || val > 11)...